# Find the Largest Common Number

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

The code I'm trying to write is suppose to accept a 2D array of integers, sort each row, and then find the greatest common number between the rows. I'm running into issues on how to return an integer type back.

Currently I can't find a way to take the row array I've created and return it back as just integers. As well, I know there will be 3 rows total imputed from test, but the column amount is unknown.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FindCommon {

/*
 * @param a 3xN integer array, assume a is not null or empty
 * @return the largest common number among a[0], a[1], a[2],  null if no  common number exists
 */
public static Integer getLargestCommonNumber(int[][] a) {

    //Check if array is empty
    if (a == null || a.length == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    //Initialize
    int [] Row1 = a[0];
    int [] Row2 = a[1];
    int [] Row3 = a[2];

    Arrays.sort(a);

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    // Iterate through three arrays while all arrays have elements
    while (i < Row1.length && j < Row2.length && k < Row3.length)
    {
         if (Row1[i] > Row2[j] && Row2[j] > Row3[k]){
             System.out.print(Row1[i]+" ");   
             int max = Row1[i];
         }
         else if (Row2[i] > Row1[j] && Row2[j] > Row3[k]){
             System.out.print(Row2[i]+" ");
             int max = Row2[i];
         }
         else if (Row3[i] > Row1[j] && Row3[j] > Row2[k]){
             int max = Row3[i];
         }


    }
}
}
```

I have test code I'm using to solve this.

```
import org.junit.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;



public class FindCommonTest {

@Test
public void testGetLargestCommonNumber1() {
    int[][] a = {{54, 41, 43, 55, 63}, {25, 40, 48, 12, 89}, {20, 19, 90, 94, 52}};
    Integer result = FindCommon.getLargestCommonNumber(a);
    Assert.assertNull(result);
}

@Test
public void testGetLargestCommonNumber2() {
    int[][] a = {{53, 41, 43, 55, 63}, {41, 25, 48, 12, 54}, {91, 19, 90, 54, 41}};
    Integer result = FindCommon.getLargestCommonNumber(a);
    Assert.assertEquals(41, (int) result);
}   

@Test
public void testGetLargestCommonNumber3() {
    int[][] a = {{54, 41, 43, 55, 63}, {25, 41, 48, 12, 54}, {41, 19, 90, 54, 94}};
    Integer result = FindCommon.getLargestCommonNumber(a);
    Assert.assertEquals(54, (int) result);
}   

}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Do you not know how to return an integer from a method, or are you asking how to return multiple integers from a method?

Answer (score 0):

For returning Integer type back, you can just simply do this:

```
public static Integer getLargestCommonNumber(int[][] a) {
    //Check if array is empty
    if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    //Initialize
    int[] Row1 = a[0];
    int[] Row2 = a[1];
    int[] Row3 = a[2];

    Arrays.sort(a);

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    Integer max = null;
    // Iterate through three arrays while all arrays have elements
    while (i < Row1.length && j < Row2.length && k < Row3.length) {
        if (Row1[i] > Row2[j] && Row2[j] > Row3[k]) {
            System.out.print(Row1[i] + " ");
            max = Row1[i];
        } else if (Row2[i] > Row1[j] && Row2[j] > Row3[k]) {
            System.out.print(Row2[i] + " ");
            max = Row2[i];
        } else if (Row3[i] > Row1[j] && Row3[j] > Row2[k]) {
            max = Row3[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. I'm also stuck on finding the greatest common number between the three assorted arrays. Currently mines running infinitly. Is my approach to finding that number incorrect?

Comment: @Craig I address that issue in my answer

Comment: @Craig I wasn't checking the logic of your code, because your question was about how to return Integer type. Maybe you can refer to Chris Gong's answer for the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the logic within your while loop. Currently, you're not really iterating through the three arrays. Your terminating condition sounds right but as of now it's going to be an infinite loop because `i`, `j`, `k` don't change. You should increment the indices of the two arrays that contain the two smaller numbers being iterated on. Also, make sure to be consistent by using the same indices for each array. Don't interchange indices between different arrays. For example, always use `i` with `Row1`, always use `j` with `Row2` and always use `k` with `Row3`. In addition, you're not sorting each row in the 2d array correclty. You need to call `Arrays.sort()` on each row. Lastly, declare `max` outside of the while loop. Otherwise you won't be able to return it because the variable will only have a scope within the loop.

```
    //Check if array is empty
    if (a == null || a.length == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    for (int[] row : a) {
        Arrays.sort(row);
    }
    //Initialize
    int [] Row1 = a[0];
    int [] Row2 = a[1];
    int [] Row3 = a[2];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    int max = 0;
    // Iterate through three arrays while all arrays have elements
    while (i < Row1.length && j < Row2.length && k < Row3.length)
    {
         if (Row1[i] >= Row2[j] && Row1[i] >= Row3[k]){
             max = Row1[i];
             j++;
             k++;
         }
         else if (Row2[j] >= Row1[i] && Row2[j] >= Row3[k]){
             max = Row2[j];
             i++;
             k++;
         }
         else if (Row3[k] >= Row1[i] && Row3[k] >= Row2[j]){
             max = Row3[k];
             i++;
             j++;
         }
    }
```

Now when this loop ends, at least one of the arrays has been traversed through completely. Therefore, there could be the case where two rows still need to be iterated through from where they left off. To cover all cases, you'll need three while loops similar to the one above to iterate through the rest of the other two rows.

```
while(i < Row1.length && j < Row2.length) {
    if(Row1[i] >= Row2[j]){
        max = Row1[i];
        j++;
    }
    else{
        max = Row2[j];
        i++;
    }
}
while(i < Row1.length && k < Row3.length) {
    if(Row1[i] > Row3[k]){
        max = Row1[i];
        k++;
    }
    else{
        max = Row3[k];
        i++;
    }
}
while(j < Row2.length && k < Row3.length) {
    if(Row2[j] >= Row3[k]){
        max = Row2[j];
        k++;
    }
    else{
        max = Row3[k];
        j++;
    }
}
return max;
```

And lastly, make sure to return `max` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to have virtually any number of rows.

```
public static Integer getLargestCommonNumber(int[][] a) {

    // Check if array is empty
    if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Initialize, we are going to create a List (matrix) of Lists (rows)
    List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int[] aRow = a[i];
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j< aRow.length; j++) {
            row.add(aRow[j]);
        }
        matrix.add(row);

    }

    // sort the rows with largest number on the left
    for (List<Integer> row : matrix) {
        Collections.sort(row, new Comparator<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return -1 * o1.compareTo(o2);
            }});
    }

    // get just the first row
    List<Integer> row0 = matrix.get(0);
    // loop through each value in the row, from largest to smallest
    for (Integer row0Value : row0) {
        int count0 = 0; // this is a counter that just adds the row numbers
        int count1 = 0; // this is a counter that adds the row numbers of rows that have a match
        // loop through rows 2 to N
        for(int i = 1; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
            count0 += i; // add to the total row counter
            if (matrix.get(i).contains(row0Value)) {
                count1 += i; // add to counter only if there was a match in this row
            }
        }
        if (count0 == count1) { // if the value is in all rows then both counters should be the same
            return row0Value;
        }
    }
    // there were no values that matched in all of the rows
    return 0;
}
```